# How does mySQL order by datetime?

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-order-by

How will mySQL order by a datetime field when it encounters 2 entries with the exact same datetime ?
How will it handle that situation?

Comment: `ORDER BY datetime, next_column_you_want_to_order`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sorting, MySQL reads all rows by key or by table scanning. Then, as it gets every row matching filter conditions, it runs qsort from zero to multiple times.

Guess it's all about first found, first served, which often related to the order they were inserted.

PS. You shouldn't rely on this. As told in other answer, use an additional ordering criteria.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add another order field: `ORDER BY datetime_fied, second_order_field`

Answer (score 1):

there is no specific order as such, when values are equal.

also you cannot assume that the order will be same every time.

see here for details :

[How mysql order the rows with same values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662837/how-mysql-order-the-rows-with-same-values)

so, it would be better if you add one more field to your order by

```
ORDER BY datetime_fied, anotherField
```