# In Activerecord if the order field is all the same, is there any default order?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been struggling with this a while. I have a Document model which has many items

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy, order: 'weight ASC'
  ...
end
```

As you can see I'm ordering the children by a weight field (integer with 0 as default). My question comes when all the weigths are the same, in most of the situations the children looks like they're ordered by ID but in a few they are not, looking so random. Is there any particular order when the order fields has the same value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced the same. Some times result will not sort in the order of id. Better, add id order also.

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy, order: 'weight ASC, id ASC'
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that detail is implementation dependent. And there's no guarantee that your Documents will be in the same order if you run this query again. There's a link to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662837/how-mysql-order-the-rows-with-same-values) with a couple of answers.